# How do you save an image to the camera roll/photos album in iOS 6/7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

It seems most methods point toward `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()`, but in iOS 6 and above you need user permission to write to the camera roll, so if they say "no" I want to be able to invoke code.

Is there a block-based method that allows me to invoke code on "failure"?

Comment: The third parameter of this function is a completionSelector which will be called if it fails.

Answer (score 8):

check this

```
/* Save to the photo album */
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave ,
                               self, // send the message to 'self' when calling the callback
                               @selector(thisImage:hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:usingContextInfo:), // the selector to tell the method to call on completion
                               NULL); // you generally won't need a contextInfo here);

- (void)thisImage:(UIImage *)image hasBeenSavedInPhotoAlbumWithError:(NSError *)error usingContextInfo:(void*)ctxInfo {
if (error) {
    // Do anything needed to handle the error or display it to the user
} else {
    // .... do anything you want here to handle
    // .... when the image has been saved in the photo album
}
}
```